# How to run multiple co-routines until completion

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following:

```
import asyncio
import pathlib

import cdo

CDO = cdo.Cdo()

async def cdo_timmean(input_files):
    outputname = await CDO.timmean(input="-select,name=temp2 "+" ".join(input_files))
    return outputname  # will be a string  

async def cdo_fldmean(input_files):
    outputname = await CDO.fldmean(input="-select,name=temp2 "+" ".join(input_files))
    return outputname  # will be a string

input_files = pathlib.Path("/isibhv/projects/paleo_repo/simulation_repository/incoming/conpi/output/")
input_files = [str(filepath) for filepath in list(input_files.glob("*echam5_main_mm*nc"))]

timmean = cdo_timmean(input_files)
fldmean = cdo_fldmean(input_files)
```

I am confused how to use asyncio to run these two co-routines. The `CDO.timmean` and `CDO.fldmean` methods will, in both cases, start subprocesses.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem(s) are you having?

Comment: Look up `asyncio.gather()` and `asyncio.run()`.